# Change videos with button

Tags: html, css, iframe

Hi I have 2 buttons and 2 videos in my page but I want to have only one video in my screen and if I want to watch another I need only click the second button. Do I need javascript or is there any simple way?

https://jsfiddle.net/xfyL11tt/

```
<h2><u>Cats</u></h2>
<div id="random-tab-id-408" class="tabs-shortcode  tabs-shortcode-top">
<ul class="tabs-shortcode-list">
<li  ><a href="#cat2" >Cat 1</a></li>
<li  ><a href="#cat1" >Cat 2</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="cat1"  >
<div class="embed-box">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tntOCGkgt98" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cat2"  >
<div class="embed-box">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yAIGLAgEa84" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: you can do this with the help of java-script.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll want to use JavaScript for this.

Here's a solution using jQuery, which is a JS library (it's not mandatory, but easier to work with):

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xfyL11tt/2/)

```
$("[data-cat-link]").on("click", function () {
    var catLink = $(this).data("cat-link");
    $(".cat")
        .hide()
        .filter("#cat" + catLink).show();
});
```

---

The links look like this:

```
<a data-cat-link="1">Cat 1</a>
```

The videos' containers look like this:

```
<div id="cat1" class="cat" >
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

include jQuery library,
put a class for `#cat1` and `#cat2` , 
edit the value of button to make it as index,
and use this js function

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.tabs-shortcode-list li a').click(function(){
          jQuery('.video').hide();
          jQuery('#cat'+$(this).attr('href')).show();
    });
});
```

and add this to your css :

```
.video{display:none;}
#cat1{display:block;}
```

[See my FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xfyL11tt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this....

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#second").hide();
    $("#C2").click(function(){
     $("#second").show();
        $("#first").hide();
    });
    
     $("#C1").click(function(){
     $("#first").show();
        $("#second").hide();
    });
    
});
```

```css
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

div {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><u>Cats</u></h2>
<div id="random-tab-id-408" class="tabs-shortcode  tabs-shortcode-top">
<ul class="tabs-shortcode-list">
<li id="C1"><a href="#cat2" >Cat 1</a></li>
<li id="C2"><a href="#cat1" >Cat 2</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="cat1"  >
<div class="embed-box" id="first">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tntOCGkgt98" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cat2"  >
<div class="embed-box" id="second">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yAIGLAgEa84" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle---](https://jsfiddle.net/xfyL11tt/)